# Tensorflow NodeJS - serialize/deserialize a model without writing it to a URI

Tags: node.js, tensorflow

Using Tensorflow in NodeJS. I have trained a model using:

```
const model = await model.fit(inputs, expected, {
    epochs: 100,
    shuffle: true,
    batchSize: 100,
    verbose: 0
});
```

Now I want to take that model and serialize it to a string value. Note I don't want to save it to the file system or an API endpoint (`model.save(...)`), I want to store a representation of it in a variable (i.e. I want a variable that contains the same value as I'd find in a file if I used `model.save(...)`).

I'd like something like `model.serialize()` that returns me the model as a string or a JSON object with the weights and such like included so I can later reconstruct my model without being forced to read from a file system or having to load each weight, unit etc manually.

Answer (score 11):

OK I found a way to do this, and I'll post below in case anyone else needs help:

To save a model to a JSON string:

```
let result = await model.save(tf.io.withSaveHandler(async modelArtifacts => modelArtifacts));
result.weightData = Buffer.from(result.weightData).toString("base64");
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Then to load again:

```
const json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
const weightData = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(json.weightData, "base64")).buffer;
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(json.modelTopology, json.weightSpecs, weightData));
```

The messing around with weightData was necessary because ArrayBuffer was not serializing to JSON. Be nice if there was a way to avoid this.

This was with @tensorflow/tfjs-node v1.0.3

Comment: thanks for this. was looking for a way to store the tensorflow model in a mongoDb database. i think this will work

Comment: Better than a great answer.  Using this method, one can spawn multiple web workers and not have to load their model into each worker (causing multiple network calls)... you can load the model in the main thread and pass it to each worker in the pool.  Be warned that TF has updated `fromMemory()` to accept a single argument that is the object `{modelTopology: json.modelTopology, :weightSpecs: json.weightSpecs, weightData: weightData}`.  Also, be sure to use `tf.loadGraphModel()` if you are this is the format you used to train your model.